# Proof that matrix A is invertible iff A is row equivalent to an upper diagonal matrix with no 0 on the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading Serge Lang's book "Linear Algebra"
He states this:

Theorem 5.6. A square matrix A is invertible if and only if A is row equivalent to the unit matrix. Any upper triangular matrix with non- zero diagonal elements is invertible.

Proof: Suppose that A is row equivalent to the unit matrix. Then A is invertible by Proposition 5.5. Suppose that A is invertible. We have just seen that A is row equivalent to an upper triangular matrix with non- zero elements on the diagonal.

However, his line "we have just seen that A is row equivalent to an upper triangular matrix with non-zero elements on the diagonal" comes out of nowhere. Nowhere preceding this line did he show that to be true, he seemingly just stated that he showed it, without having showed it. Intuitively it makes sense, but I want to see the proof. We have so far not discussed eigenvectors or determinants or really much at all, so I can't use those for a proof.

Help appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this statement come after any discussing of Gaussian elimination or reduction to row echelon form?

Comment: Does your book have this bit of text literally right before theorem 5.6: *"By Theorem 4.1 we know that A is row equivalent to a matrix A' in echelon form. If one row of A' is zero, then by the definition of echelon form, the last row must be zero, and A' is not invertible, hence A is not invertible. If all the rows of A' are non-zero, then A' is a triangular matrix with non-zero diagonal components."*? (the one I'm looking at does!)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen yes it does have that bit of text. But the part where it says "...the last row must be zero, and A' is not invertible, hence A is not invertible" also has no justification. In this sentence he states that A' is not invertible. How do we know that? He states it here and then again in the proof, with no prior justification

Comment: @whpowell96 Yes it does. We have a theorem stating that any Matrix can be reduced to row echelon form. However the definition of row echelon form allows for bottoms rows of all zeros, and there is no discussion about how a row of zeros makes a matrix uninvertible. He just states it as fact

Comment: You are capable of proving this fact directly.  Assume that row $m$ of $n \times n$ matrix $A$ consists of all zeros and let $B$ be any $n \times n$ matrix.  What can you say about the $m$th row of $AB$?  In particular, is it possible that $AB=I$?

Comment: @RobertShore thank you...should've been obvious to me...thought I missed something